# Exporting in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following structure in my file1; now in file2 I just want to have access to "func1" not the other parts:

```
module.exports = function(_app) {
    .
    .
    .
}

function func1(param1) {
    .
    .
    .
}

module.exports.func1 = func1;
```

now in file2 when I have the following does it load just func1 or module.exports = function(_app) {} as well? If so how can I just use func1 in file2.

```
var file1 = require('file1');
file1.func1
```

Thanks; if you need more clarification please let me know...

Comment: function export is under control of the exporting module, not the one doing the import.

Comment: so when in file2 I say var file1 = require('file1'); doies it import all of the exported ones? How can I just import func1 in file2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
var func1 = require('file1').func1;
```

Strictly speaking this imports the entire module, but discards the references to the other functions.

If you want to actually invoke the function that you've replaced `module.exports` with then you'd need to write this first:

```
require('file1')(app);  // invoke f(_app)
```

To do it in one line would require `f(_app)` to also `return module.exports` so you could chain the calls:

```
var func1 = (require('file1')(app)).func1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much; just could you please let me know whether I'm correct or not: by var func1 = require('file1') does already execute the content of function(_app) as well; if no how can I call that function; sorry I'm kind of new to Node...

Comment: No, it won't execute that function, you'd have to do it explicitly